# Solving a complex equation with Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve:

$e^{-b (1.365)} + e^{-b(-0.350)} + e^{-b(-0.378)} = 0$, where $b$ is complex.

So, I have written:

```
Solve[{E^((-b1 - I b2) (1.365)) + E^((-b1 - I b2) (-0.350)) + E^((-b1 - I b2) (-0.378)) == 0, {b1, b2} \[Element] Reals}, {b1,b2}]
```

which returns a huge list. How can I get a exact answer? And if it has many solutions, is it possible that I plot the solution points altogether in the complex plane?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I suggest you use `Solve[Rationalize[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.378)), 0] == 0, b]`.  It still gives a list of 249 solutions, but they have some semblance of a pattern.  Of them, you may be looking for the first one, which is simpler.  Also, perhaps the coefficients in the exponentials are only approximate.  I suggest you use the exact values, which may lead to some simplifications.

Comment: Use `ListPlot`.

Comment: Basically you are solving `eb^54 + eb^50 + eb^395 == 0` where `eb = Exp[-b*7/1000]`. High degree polynomial --> large solution set. Of course this has infinitely many solutions, and the transformation above will only give a finite subset once you write `b` in terms of the log of `eb`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  I believe that `395` in your comment should be `-195`.  With that change, and factoring out `eb^-195` yields the equation `1 + eb^245 + eb^249 == 0`, which is the same expression appearing in the `Root` functions of the `249` solutions.

Comment: @bgodfrey Right, I missed a sign and did some seriously derelict counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the plot you are seeking:

```
Solve[Rationalize[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.378)), 0] == 0, b]
ListPlot[ReIm[b /. % /. C[1] -> 0], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Choosing different integer values for `C[1]` simply shifts the plot vertically by the corresponding multiple of `2 Pi`.  Please consider using rational expressions for the three coefficients instead of decimal approximations, if they exist.

Addendum: Number of solutions exceeds 1000.

The OP asked in a comment below why using the method presented above on a particular new set of coefficients did not yield a solution in a reasonable amount of time.  The reason is that system parameter, `$MaxRootDegree` must be increased from its default value of `1000` to a number at least as large as the number of solutions, here `1783`.

```
$MaxRootDegree = 1783;    
Solve[Rationalize[E^(-b (3.077)) + E^(-b (2.676)) + E^(-b (1.294)), 0] == 0, b]
ListPlot[ReIm[b /. %% /. C[1] -> 0], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, are you now trying to solve `E^(-b (3.077)) + E^(-b (2.676)) + E^(-b (1.294)), == 0`; in other words, are all three coefficients of `- b` positive?

Comment: @Ralf I expect that that my code will provide an answer, if you wait long enough.  That answer will have 1783 solutions.

Comment: @Ralf  I can write the solution by inspection, `Table[{b -> (1000*(2 I Pi C[1] +       Log[Root[1 + #1^401 + #1^1783 &, n, 0]]))}, {n, 1783}]` and will add the plot when I return from a party.